# How do I prevent AWS Lambda from reusing database connections?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I have a helper class that I created to provide access to shared functionality for all my lambda functions. For example, it has a helper method to create a new IRepository for me to query my database. The helper is declared outside of my handler, here is what it looks like:

```
public partial class Program {        
    static LambdaHelper helper;
}

var handler = async (APIGatewayProxyRequest req, ILambdaContext context) => {  
    helper = new LambdaHelper();
    //call to GetRepository always creates a new instance of the repo
    var myRepo = helper.GetRepository<SomeType>(); 
    //all repo methods create a dbconnection inside a using block so it should be disposed 
    var data = myRepo.GetAll();  
}
```

As I understood it, any variable declared within the handler will not be re-used between invocations if Lambda uses the same container on a subsequent calls all those variables will be recreated. But that does not seem to be the case here and I'll see a bunch of sleeping connections in MySQL. I changed the wait_timeout in MySQL to be 10 mins and while that cleaned up the waiting connections for me I'll now get errors in lambda when it tries to re-use a container after that 10 mins expires, I will get a timeout exception on the call.

It's as if the helper being declared outside the handler is causing this issue, but the odd part is that the helper class doesn't keep any references to anything internally other than the AWSSecrets it loads upon start.

Any idea what's going on here and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Connector/NET (which I assume you're using) uses the technology known as [connection pooling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-pooling.html).

Instances of `MySqlConnection`, behind the scenes, keep a reference to a static object that is managing the pool of connections.

When you first create an instance of `MySqlConnection` with a certain connection string and call `Open` on it, the pool manager allocates a number of network connections to your database instance and binds one of them to `MySqlConnection` you've created. All other instances of `MySqlConnection` using the same string will take the available connections from the pool.

Disposing of `MySqlConnection` or calling `Close` on it does not close the underlying network connection to the server. The pool manager just returns it to the pool.

> As I understood it, any variable declared within the handler will not be re-used between invocations if Lambda uses the same container on a subsequent calls all those variables will be recreated.

This is true, but it doesn't mean that the object that this variable references (directly or indirectly) will not be the same. Different variables can reference the same object, and that's exactly what's happening here.

> How do I prevent AWS Lambda from reusing database connections?

To answer your question directly: set `Pooling=false` in your [connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0):

> `Pooling`. When the value of this key is set to true, any newly created connection will be added to the pool when closed by the application. In a next attempt to open the same connection, that connection will be drawn from the pool.

That said, connection pooling is a good thing. It's not that much of a problem with MySQL as with other database engines, but even in MySQL connections are a very expensive managed resource. There is no point creating and dropping connections for each invocation of the handler. It will put load on the server, and AWS will bill you for the extra time your lambdas will waste on waiting for the connection to be created.

Lambda handlers run serially (within a single container). You should evaluate how many connections each invocation of your handler concurrently uses, and set the pool size to this number by using the parameters `Max Pool Size` and `Min Pool Size` in your connection string.

This number might as well be 1 (if you're not creating multiple connections used by concurrent tasks or threads). In this case, just set the pool size to 1. Each invocation of your Lambda will use the same database connection, which is a good thing if your handlers are running back-to-back.